# Bi-Planar YUV 4:2:0 pixel manipulation with Accelerate framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, accelerate-framework

Is there any possible way to manipulate YUV 4:2:0 bi-planar video with Accelerate framework directly?

or do I have to follow steps bellow for the flip operation for instance?

1. `vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888`
2. `vImageHorizontalReflect_ARGB8888`
3. `vImageConvert_ARGB8888To420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8`

Answer (score 0):

If you have three buffers to pass to `vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888`, you can simply call `vImageHorizontalReflect_Planar8` on each buffer.

Many vImage functions actually deinterleave buffers ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/optimizing_image-processing_performance)), so there's a good chance calling the planar reflect function three times may be faster than calling the interleaved variant.